# How do you deal with fractions in a binomial?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

If I have something like this
$$\binom{\frac{x}{k}}{\frac{y}{k}}$$

(where there are two fractions in a binomial but they have the same denominator) can I simplify this at all?

Comment: This I have never seen.  Where did it come from?

Comment: @DanUznanski I'm working through a problem and I had to substitute a fraction for a variable I had in a binomial.

Answer (score 1):

how did you come across such thing? You could use the definition for integers, and replace factorials of the fraction with the Gamma function $x! = \Gamma(x+1)$.

Comment: I'm working through a problem and I had to substitute a fraction for a variable I had in a binomial. Maybe I can find something else to substitute.

Answer (score 1):

The calculator can calculate factorial of any real number . the curves of factorial is a $smooth curve$. The calculator use $\Gamma$ function which has following properties $(x!)=\Gamma(x+1)$ ,$\Gamma (x+1)=x \Gamma(x)$ and for real number we can use stirling approximation which can be found out in many answers on MSE. If you want one i can give you a link .

Answer (score 0):

> If I know that there are $n$ external nodes on a tree, how many internal nodes are there if all nodes are either leaves or have $x$ children?

This might get flagged, but it seems like this is your actual question from the comments.

Take an existing tree with $n$ external nodes and $m$ internal nodes that satisfies your constraints. The only way to construct a tree with mode nodes is to take a leaf node and give it $x$ children.

This produces a tree with $n + 7$ external nodes and $m + 1$ internal nodes. As you can see, these are linear relationships between the trees.

Starting with the smallest such tree, the one of only a root leaf, we can count the external nodes and internal nodes after $i$ iterations.

$$
n = 1 + 7i \\
m = i
$$

From this, we can get the number of internal nodes as a function of external nodes.

$$
m = \frac{n - 1}{7}
$$

Whatever you were actually doing, doesn't seem like it would have been fruitful even if you succeeded with fractional coefficients.

Comment: The comment has since been removed, but I've got it quoted for record keeping.